# Can we use allOf in OpenAPI /components/parameters to override attributes of a referenced parameter?

Tags: openapi, swagger-editor

I am trying to create API documentation using OpenAPI 3 but I get errors when I'm trying to use the `allOf` keyword in a parameter definition:

```yaml
components:
  parameters:
    idParam:
      name: id
      in: path
      description: ID of the boxx
      required: true
      schema:
        type: string
        format: int65
    dataSourceID:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/parameters/idParam'
        - name: dataSourceID
          description: ID of the data source
```

> Schema error at components.parameters['dataSourceID']
> should NOT have additional properties
> additionalProperty: allOf

Is is possible to reuse the values of another parameter? Maybe in a different way?

Comment: Related: [How can I setup a path to use a parameter reference and override the name property?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68588082/113116), [Is it possible to override the "required" attribute of a referenced parameter in OpenAPI 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56901628/113116)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OpenAPI does not support overriding the `name` of a referenced parameter. Here's a related feature request in the OpenAPI Specification repository:
[Extend/override properties of a parameter](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/2026)

In OpenAPI 3.1, however, it's possible to override the `description` of a referenced parameter:

```yaml
# openapi: 3.1.0

components:
  parameters:
    ...

    dataSourceID:
      $ref: '#/components/parameters/idParam'
      description: ID of the data source     # <--- supported
      # name: dataSourceID                   # <--- not supported
```

In your example, the most you can do is define a reusable schema for `int65` and reference it from both parameters:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
...

components:
  schemas:
    int65:
      type: string
      format: int65

  parameters:
    idParam:
      name: id
      in: path
      description: ID of the boxx
      required: true
      schema:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/int65'   # <-----
    dataSourceID:
      name: dataSourceID
      in: path
      description: ID of the data source
      required: true
      schema:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/int65'   # <-----
```

Comment: Thanks, though it's a bit disappointing that it's not possible.

Comment: @select Feel free to submit a feature request in the OpenAPI Specification repository: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues

Comment: I guess line  "allOf is not supported in parameters, paths, and other places." is misnomer as allOf is supported on schema Objects and parameters, paths may contain the schema Objects.

Hence allOf can also be used under parameters, paths which has schema object.

Answer (score -1):

I guess `allOf` can be used in parameters schema as below.

`allOf` can be used in schema objects only.
And since **parameters**,**paths** may contain `schema` objects `allOf` can be used in parameters as follows.

```
components:
  parameters:
    idParam:
      name: id
      in: path
      description: ID of the boxx
      required: true
      schema:
        type: string
        format: int65
    dataSourceID:
      name: dataSourceID
      in: path
      description: dataSourceID of the boxx
      schema:
         allOf:
          - $ref: '#/components/parameters/idParam'
          - type: object
              properties:
                name:
                  type: string
                description:
                  type: string
```

Comment: This is not a valid spec - $refs inside `schema` can only point to other schemas (e.g. to `#/components/schemas/...`) but not to parameters.