# Is it possible to override the "required" attribute of a referenced parameter in OpenAPI 3?

Tags: openapi

I'm building a simple OpenAPI 3 YAML specification like this:

```yaml
paths:
  /query:
    get:
      parameters:
        - $ref: '#/components/parameters/bookid'

components:
  parameters:
    bookid:
      in: query
      name: bookid
      required: false
      schema:
        format: integer
        type: number
```

Now, I'd like to use the common `bookid` **parameter** but overriding the `required` value from `false` to `true`. For example (that doesn't work!!!):

```yaml
paths:
  ...

  /query2:
    get:
      parameters:
        - $ref: '#/components/parameters/bookid'
          required: true  # <--- ???
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: On an unrelated note, consider using `type: integer` instead of `type: number` + `format: integer`.

Answer (score 5):

This is not supported. You need separate parameter definitions for required and optional parameters.

As of OpenAPI 3.1, you can only override the `description` of a referenced parameter, but not other attributes (`required`, `name` and others).

```yaml
# openapi: 3.1.0

parameters:
  # This works
  - $ref: '#/components/parameters/bookid'
    description: Custom description

  # This won't work - cannot override attributes other than "description"
  - $ref: '#/components/parameters/bookid'
    required: true
```

Here are existing feature requests:

- [Extend/override properties of a parameter](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/2026)
- [Allow required as sibling of $ref (like summary/description)](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/2498)

Comment: But, creating two **parameters**? One `bookid` with `required: false` and another, named `bookid_required` that is equal to the first one but with `required: true`?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: This is really bad for a programmer :-/

Comment: You can submit syntax enhancement requests to the OpenAPI Specification repository at https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues

Comment: @vlauciani you could use yaml anchors to avoid repetition.