# How can I setup a path to use a parameter reference and override the name property?

Tags: swagger, openapi

I have multiple paths that require an id number. There are some paths where multiple ids are required.

I know that I can reference a parameter when building a path.

```
paths:
  /path1/{path1ID}
    parameters:
      - $ref: '#/components/parameters/path1ID_param'

components:
  parameters:
    path1ID_param:
      name: path1ID
      in: path
        schema:
          type: integer
```

If I do it this way, I'm going to have a lot of repeated definitions where the only change is the name. This grates.

Is there a way I can override the name in the path definition? I have tried variations of `allOf` but haven't hit on anything yet. I've searched the [swagger](https://swagger.io) documentation without much luck. I've searched here and found a lot of interesting pointers that helped me refine my API ... but I found nothing related to what I'm trying to do.

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
paths:
  /path1/{path1ID}
    parameters:
      - $ref: '#/components/parameters/parmID_param/'
      - name: path1ID
  /path1/{path1ID}/subpath2/{subpath2ID}
    - $ref: '#/components/parameters/parmID_param/'
    - name: path1ID
    - $ref: '#/components/parameters/parmID_param/'
    - name: subpath2ID

components:
  parameters:
    path1ID_param:
      name: path1ID
      in: path
        schema:
          type: integer
```

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Is it possible to override the "required" attribute of a referenced parameter in OpenAPI 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56901628/113116)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported.

As of OpenAPI 3.1, you can only override the `description` of a referenced parameter, but not its `name` or other attributes (`required`, `style`, etc.).

Here are existing feature requests in the OpenAPI Specification repository:

- [Extend/override properties of a parameter](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/2026)
- [Allow required as sibling of $ref (like summary/description)](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/2498)

Comment: Thank you. Annoying, but based on the discussion on that issue, I'm not alone. :)